# Can I still have a relationship with Liara having said no to her at the beginning of the game?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I romanced Liara in Mass Effect 1. In Mass Effect Two, however, I romanced Miranda as well.  In Mass Effect Three when Liara asks if were still  together in the beginning of the game and I said we should just be friends, will I have another chance to be in a relationship her later in the game?

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

I declined her in the start of the game. And we ended up as a couple of sorts in the end.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that if you follow it up and pursue her romantically, you should be able to roamnce her just like a character who didn't romance her in ME1 can. The options to lock in the ormance are pretty far in, so I woudln't think this early response would lock you out.